# My webpage constantly refreshes when trying to connect my HTML using JavaScript with NodeJS backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, counter

I am trying to keep track of visitors and page views in my website, just a simple feature to show in my webpage but the page is constantly refreshed after starting my backend server, increasing the count of my page views.

HTML code:

```
<h2>Page Views: <span id="pageviews-count"></span></h2>
<h2>Visits: <span id="visits-count"></span></h2>
```

Script for HTML:

```
const pageviewsCount = document.getElementById('pageviews-count');
const visitsCounts = document.getElementById('visits-count');

if (sessionStorage.getItem('visit') === null) {
    updateCounter('type=visit-pageview');
}
else {
    updateCounter('type=pageview');
}

function updateCounter(type) {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/counter?' + type)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            pageviewsCount.textContent = data.pageviews;
            visitsCounts.textContent = data.visits;
        })
}
```

counter.controller.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function visitCounter(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.end();
    }

    const json = fs.readFileSync('./logs/count.json', 'utf-8');
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);

    obj.pageviews = obj.pageviews + 1;

    if (req.query.type === 'visit-pageview') {
        obj.visits = obj.visits + 1;
    }

    const newJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
    fs.writeFileSync('./logs/count.json', newJson);

    res.send(newJson);

}

module.exports = visitCounter
```

counter.routes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const counter = require('../controllers/counter.controller');

const router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(counter);

module.exports = router;
```

count.json:

```
{"pageviews":369,"visits":8}
```

And finally, app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const port = 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/counter', require('./routes/counter.routes'));
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: There must be something else in your code environment that triggers this refresh

Comment: I wrote this code after I completed the webpage, which was working fine. But after inserting the code above, it started acting weird and refreshes every second. If you have any specific targets about the code, I can post it, but I doubt anything else is causing it because it worked before just fine.

Comment: do you have some `<form>` in your page that is being automatically submitted? Or perhaps you're (mis)using some framework like react/angular etc? surerly your web page has more than two elements and a dozen lines of javascript

Comment: Hmm...I do have a form in my HTML but it is unrelated with the code above, it only submits when I click on Send. But I will try to comment it out and re-run it. I am not using any frameworks, the frontend is HTML, JS, CSS and the backend is NodeJs and ExpressJs, nothing else.